# Is It Possible to create a music player with PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I was thinking of creating a music player with waveform like in zippyshare like this for my project

http://www52.zippyshare.com/v/41958620/file.html

I was thinking of getting the song in my local server then it will be played with javascript.

how can I do that??

Comment: It is never helpful to ask if something is possible. We can not say (and we do not want to judge you on) what is **possible for you**.

Comment: let me rephrase the question.

Comment: Concerning audio stuff you should **definetly** check out this video from Google I/O 2011 (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WlwY6_W4VG8). The talk about HTML5 Audio starts at about 37:00, the *really* nasty stuff starts at ca. 42:00. This goes *way* beyond zippyshare, and the best thing about it is that it only uses native HTML5 elements. And it's just incredible! And awesome... Incredibly awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A website that plays audio would either use flash or the new html5 `<audio>` tag. The creator would use the php you would generate a `src=` and then link the controls to buttons. From there you have a working audio player. More info on the audio tag [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp)

Waveform generation would be difficult in this project. PHP wouldn't be your tool of choice for this matter so your best bet would be to find a library that can generate audio waveform. Although apparently [this guy](http://andrewfreiday.com/2010/04/29/generating-mp3-waveforms-with-php/) found a way to do it.

Comment: can you post also about the waveform?

Comment: what I was thinking is loading the song in PHP then generate the waveform with javascript

Comment: @user962206: You are invited to use the search on this site. I can tell you a secret: This has been asked (and answered) before, and the answer in this case is really cool.

Comment: I tried to search this site but couldn't find any.

Comment: Look for the [Web Audio API Draft](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html) (webkit) or [Audio Data API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API) (Mozilla)